# iOS - Navigation Title Not Updating

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

What I'm doing with this bit of code is grabbing an image sequence, grabbing it's name. Then setting the view's title as the sequences name playing the sequence then setting the title back to the old title.

Problem is the title doesn't seem to be changing on the navigation bar. The NSLogs are outputting the correct values though.

I remember having this issue before and solving it with some "refresh" method.

Here is the pertinent code.

```
-(void)playSequence
{
 if (([animatorViewController isAnimating] == FALSE) && (btnDisable == FALSE))
 {
  Sequence *tempSequence;
  tempSequence = [fullStepList objectAtIndex:lastPlayedSequence];
  self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Assembly - %@", tempSequence.subName];
  NSLog(self.title);
  [self startAnimator:tempSequence.imageNameScheme forNumFrames:tempSequence.numberOfFrames playInReverse:FALSE];
  tempSequence = nil;
  tempSequence = [fullStepList objectAtIndex:queuedSequence];
  self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Assembly - %@", tempSequence.subName];
  NSLog(self.title);
  tempSequence = nil;
 }
}
```

EDIT: This method of changing the title is working else where in this class. The problem seems to come in when trying to set it twice that is causing the issue.

EDIT2: It's actually running both title changes one after another... Fact that it was setting it back to previous was throwing me off.

Comment: Is self a UIView or a UIViewController?

Comment: try to replace `self.title` with `self.navigationItem.title`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The dreaded P.E.B.K.A.C. error was the cause of this confusion. It's actually running both title changes one after another... Fact that it was setting it back to previous was throwing me off.

Answer (score 2):

A navigation item may contains four things: leftBarButtonItem, rightBarButtonItem, title, and titleView. When you need to change the title you should assign your title to navigationItem's title property, not to your view's title property. So it would look like:

```
self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Assembly - %@", tempSequence.subName];
```

self.title points to your viewControllers title which don't shows up in the navigationBar.

Answer (score 1):

The title won't appear to update until after the main run loop executes.  Unless `-startAnimator:forNumFrames:` invokes the main run loop to execute before it returns, you won't see the change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting the UINavigationController inside another view, you need to do this:

```
self.yourNavigationController.title = @"title";
```

instead of

```
self.title = @"blah"
```

Otherwise you are just changing the title of the view hosting the view navigator. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found myself in a similar situation. My view's title was comprised of a label with an NSMutableAttributedString. Calling `[self reloadInputViews]` whenever I updated my title worked for me.